# Malt Extract not properly sealed

Tags: malt, extract-brewing, spoilage

I am about to brew one of my first beers (using the malt extract brewing method), however when my ingredients arrived one of the bags was not quite sealed and some extract had leaked out. The loss of quantity is not an issue as I had slightly over ordered due to bag sizes. Will the extract remaining in the packet be okay to use?

It does not look/smell to be spoiled.

Any more info required please ask, and thanks in advance

Comment: As long as it's still a powder I think it should be fine. I think the main enemy of powder extract is moisture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it was contaminated, as long as you plan on boiling it, it will be safe. If it was very spoiled (smelled bad), then it might have fewer sugars and the end result may taste bad. Otherwise, you should be fine.